# Remote image not showing with live server

Tags: html, atom-liveserver

Remote images not showing in react and live server but showing when opened normally

[image: index file]

[image: output when opened index file normally]

[image: output when opened with live-server]

[image: error]

`<img src="https://dell.ibomma.pw/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/Geetha-Saakshiga-Telugu-bgs7m-2023-230x345.jpg" alt="img">`
I saved this code in index.html
When i open index.html in browser, image is showing
But when i open with live server image is not showing ,getting error
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
Same problem in react app also
And also when i use vidstack player video not loading getting same error
but playing normal video tags

Comment: Can you provide logs and also check whether the file is requested in the network tab or not and if yes then what's the response of that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.